Foundry: Member "getBlockTimestamp" not found
I'm trying to use a method from foundry which is located here in the documentation
When I try to call it like so:
uint256 timestamp = vm.getBlockTimestamp();

I'm getting an error:

Member "getBlockTimestamp" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Vm.

I've already ran foundry-up and I'm on the latest implementation of forge.  All of the other standard vm functions are working fine.  e.g vm.startPrank etc...

Only thing I can possibly think of is, maybe the project is using an outdated version of foundry since it was, installed prior to me running the latest foundry-up,   maybe I need to update the foundry contracts in the project not sure exactly how to do that.

It should work fine. Can you add the portion of the code where you're using that?

sometimes , surprisingly, i get the same error and it works by removing the 'vm."

Even if you are running the most recent version of forge, this doesn't determine what has been pulled down in your forge-std submodule. You could try running  git submodule to see what hash of the forge-std is being used. Make sure you have (v1.7.5) or later to use the vm.getBlockTimestamp() cheatcode.
example-native-token-transfers % git submodule 
 36c303b7ffdd842d06b1ec2744c9b9b5fb3083f3 evm/lib/forge-std (v1.7.5)

